# Dynamic Table alternate background - MVC3

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc-3, html-table

I have two tables in my view; trying to change the background of alternate rows in one table.  In my style file I am using:

```
 .alternateRow
{
    table-layout: auto;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-spacing: 0px;
    empty-cells: hide;
}

.alternateRow tr {
     background-color:#aa0000;

}

.alternateRow tr.odd  {
     background-color:#00AA00;

}
```

This is how I make the dynamic table:

```
<table class="alternateRow">
        <% List<Question> wrongs = ViewBag.wrongs;
       for (var i = 0; i < wrongs.Count; ++i)
       { %>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <%= wrongs[i].TheQuestion %>
            </td>
            <td>
                Correct Answer
            </td>
            <td>
                <%= wrongs[i].CorrectAnswer %>
            </td>
            <td>
                <%= wrongs[i].Explanations %>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <% } %>
```

I did not work, both rows have the same color.  Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Comment: You aren't defining the use of class `odd` anywhere in your HTML.

Comment: Tried to use the following:   $('table.alternateRow').append(function (i, h) {
                    var tr = '<tr';
                    if ($(this).children('tr').size() % 2 == 0)
                        tr += ' class="odd"';
                    tr += '></tr>';
                    return tr;
                });
but did not work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what you can do:

```
<% List<Question> wrongs = ViewBag.wrongs;
for (var i = 0; i < wrongs.Count; ++i)
{ 
    var rowClass = ((i % 2) == 0 ? "" : "odd"); // or whatever your alternate row class is
%>
    <tr class="<%= rowClass %>">
        <td>
            <%= wrongs[i].TheQuestion %>
        </td>
        <td>
            Correct Answer
        </td>
        <td>
            <%= wrongs[i].CorrectAnswer %>
        </td>
        <td>
            <%= wrongs[i].Explanations %>
        </td>
    </tr>
<% } %>
```